# How do I make a local copy of a branch on my github?

Tags: git, github

I currently have a branch on my github called `gh-pages`. Locally, I cannot tell that this branch exists. Is there a way to be able to move to this branch? Could I somehow make a branch of it locally?

Thanks

Comment: "Locally, I cannot tell that this branch exists" - you can. `git fetch && git branch -a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all branches locally using `git branch -a`. You can fetch all remote branches locally using `git fetch` or fetch a single remote branch locally using `git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages`. You can check out branches then locally using `git checkout gh-pages`